# Touchpad stopped working: [Acer Nitro 5 Ryzen 7 5800H]

Tags: touchpad, acer, 21.10

Configuration Details: Acer Nitro 5 Ryzen 7 5800H (Radeon with RTX 3060)
OS Details: Ubuntu 21.10, NVIDIA driver 495

The touchpad was working fine with Ubuntu 21.10. Yesterday I updated using apt-get, and there was some kernel update and related packages. I said 'y' and updated them. After restart, the touchpad stopped working. Not only in Ubuntu but also on Windows (Its a Dual Boot system). Then I searched for solution, did not find any. I went to the Acer support site and tried to download the latest drivers and install them. There was a disclaimer at the support site, that I need to install the I/O Serial Driver first before updating the Touchpad driver else touchpad will stop working. I tried to install the Chipset driver (which includes the I/O driver, I guess), and I got 'Installation failure' (tried it twice), so I left the process. Do anyone observe this touchpad issue also? Can someone tell me what I should do now. My Ubuntu is already having NVIDIA driver 495.

Answer (score 1):

I got the touchpad working. It is nothing to do with the driver for the touchpad. The function key 'F2' in Acer Nitro 5 is a toggle switch to disable/enable the touchpad. I am so embarrassed to post this answer (but since I was trying to fix this for 3 to 4 hours in vain, thought someone in my situation can save time looking for a fix like me) and I am quite surprised though on how the toggle works across the OS --remember I told I was using Dual Boot system.